# Прошу помочь с расчетом по формуле

Tags: python, математика

Только начал изучать Питон. Написал простенькую программку по аналогии примерам из книжки.
При всей неправильности, по моему мнению, формулы full_price считается правильно, хотя на мой взгляд в формула должна выглядеть таким образом:
full_price = price + nalog + reg_fee + agency_fee + price_distance
Может кто-нибудь пояснить, как так выходит???

Вот текст программы:

```
print ( "Вас приветствует программа Автодиллер!"  )
name = input ( "Введите Ваше имя: " )
print ( "\n" )
print ( (name), "сейчас я посчитаю стоимость купленного Вами автомобиля с учётом налога, который составляет 13% от суммы " )
print ( "автомобиля, регистрационного сбора, который составляет 5% от суммы автомобиля, агентского сбора в 25 долларов США и " )
print ( "цены доставки Вашего автомобиля до указанного места назначения в зависимости от указанного Вами количества километров, " )
print ( "с учетом того, что расстояние доставки, равное 100 километрам стоит 10 долларов США \n" )
price = float ( input ( "Введите цену Вашего автомобиля в долларах США (USD): " ))
distance = float ( input ( "Введите расстояние до места доставки в километрах: " ))
nalog = (price/100)*13
reg_fee = (price/100)*5 
agency_fee = (price+25)
price_distance =  (distance*0.1)
full_price = nalog + reg_fee + agency_fee + price_distance
print ( "\n" )
print ( (name) + ", стоимость Вашего заказа в долларах США составляет: ", full_price, "USD"  )
input ( "\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти." )
# Что-то странное в формуле явно не хватает price, но иначе результат увеличивается на величину price и результат получается неверным!!!
```

Comment: Потому что `price` уже зачем-то учли в `agency_fee = (price+25)`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас `price` в `agency_fee`: `agency_fee = (price+25)`.
По условию:

> агентского сбора в 25 долларов

То есть `agency_fee` = цена автомобиля + агентский сбор

Comment: Это как бы не является ответом на вопрос. так, на комментарий тянет.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть эти критерии.